# android Prevent a view from restoring its state

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Most built-in widgets restore its state on configuration change. 
But now I have a situation when I want to disable this feature.
I set a particular view some value during onCreate() call and it's been changed during onRestoreInstanceState() if the device was rotated.
I could reset it after onRestoreInstanceState(), but maybe there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add `android:saveEnabled="false"` to the `View` (or call `setSaveEnabled(false)` programmatically). The `View` will still be recreated on a configuration change, though -- it just won't save and restore its own private state.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add this to your activity tag

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
```

This will prevent edit text from restoring when device is rotated.

Comment: what if I want some built-in to restore their states and some not?

Comment: you can use onConfigurationChanged method for that and you can control things accordingly on rotation like if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

    Log.e("On Config Change","LANDSCAPE");
}else{

    Log.e("On Config Change","PORTRAIT");
}